# Only selected columns to Gridview ASP.NET LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm having a GridView in my WebForm. I'm using LINQ to set the datasource. I want only few selected columns in the table to be displayed in GridView.

C#:

```
            var source = from s in imd.Students
                         where s.Dept_Id == 18 && s.Year == 1
                         select new { Name = s.Name };
            Marks.DataSource = source;
            Marks.DataBind();
```

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Marks" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Score">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Score" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

But I'm getting two Name columns in GridView. How could I fix this? I want Name column first and then the TextBox in second column. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `HTML` side is correct ..and here `select new { Name = s.Name , Here select score as well };` you are not selecting  score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your columns in markup, you can turn off automatic column creation:

```
<asp:GridView ... AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
```

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

```
var source = from s in imd.Students
    where s.Dept_Id == 18 && s.Year == 1
    select new { Name = s.Name, Score = s.Score };
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:GridView ID="Marks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```